# Injecting a string into a javascript on an asp.net mvc view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contains a javascript function that i need to init/call when the page loads. The method is static but it needs to be called with some parameteres (a list of Id's) - this list is dynamic and varies by some querystring parameters (i can not generate the list clientside from the querystring).

So i need to generate this list server-side.

My options are, as far as i see it:

> 1) Make an ajax call on the client, requesting the ids from the server.
>
> 2) Inject/inserting the ids directly on the view (it is a property on the viewmodel).

No matter how i turn it, option 2 seems the most sane. I already got the data ready on the viewmodel and thus it's ready when the view is populated - i see no reason to make an extra request to the server, just to get the data.

I know many would think it's a bad idea to inject something dynamic into an otherwise static javascript. For that i could simply just inject a new javascript, holding only the Ids and a call to the static javascript method, which is what i really want to do.

My problem is this though: When i write my asp.net <%= %> includes, VS IDE stops highligting, making me think i might be on the wrong track? Surely i'm not the only one needing to output something in a javascript block in asp.net mvc?

Comment: If VS stops highlighting it doesn't mean that view parser won't pick-up server side script sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 2 (The ViewModel) is definately the way to go and

```
<script type="text/javascript>
 <%= Model.JavascriptToInsert %>
</script>
```

should work (despite lack of VS highlighting)

It will NOT work in a seperate JS file though. It must be in your view itself.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: I was only thinking of putting the static javascript in a seperate js file - to seperate the static javascript from the dynamic. But thanks, this is what i'm currently doing, just wondering if i'm missing something - i hate that hightlighting is not showing up...